# trigger command to run on puppet after failure

Tags: puppet

I want to be able to call a custom action if the manifest fails. The manifest contains several calls and any of these could fail. Whatever call to file, exec, package fails would ideally trigger the same call. Is this possible in puppet? This is so I can raise an alert that the deployment has failed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this. The puppet client can send a report to the puppet master after every run. On the puppet master, you can have however many report processors you want, performing eveery functionality you want. I use it to send passive checks to nagios about puppet runs and failures for instance.

As this is quite a big subject to explain, I'll not do it badly but [link to the official documentation instead](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/reporting.html), which includes example report processors.

Answer (score 0):

Puppet can report back to the server after transactions. There are [several methods](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/report.html) for this; you may want to look into [`tagmail`](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/report.html#tagmail), which sends log messages by e-mail. From the documentation:

> To use this report, you must create a tagmail.conf file in the
>   location specified by the tagmap setting. This is a simple file that
>   maps tags to email addresses: Any log messages in the report that
>   match the specified tags will be sent to the specified email
>   addresses.